# Selecting an option in a template literal based on string

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I am creating an admin panel. On this admin panel, Super Admins will be able to edit other admins' roles. On the edit screen I have a dropdown that contains the available roles an admin can have. I am using a template literal to inject this HTML into a modal of my own design. My issue is, I am not sure how I can dynamically select the option that contains the value of the Admin's role saved in the database.

For example, if the JSON of admin data is like this `{ name: John Smith, role: admin }` how could I select  that in a template literal like this automatically:

```
`<select class="form-control" id="editRole">
      <option value="Editor">Editor</option>
      <option value="admin">Admin</option>
      <option value="Super Admin">Super Admin</option>
    </select>`
```

I tried a way like this and it does not seem to work:

```
const adminData = {name: John Smith, role: admin};

`<select class="form-control" id="editRole">
${document.querySelector('option[value*="${adminData.role}"]').selected = true}
<option value="Editor">Editor</option>
  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
  <option value="Super Admin">Super Admin</option>
</select>`
```

Comment: You're using vanilla JavaScript plus jQuery, not React/Angular/Vue here?

Comment: @jarmod Vanilla only, no jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator.

```
const adminData = {name: 'John Smith', role: 'admin'};

const str = `<select class="form-control" id="editRole">
  <option value="Editor" ${adminData.role === 'editor' ? 'selected' : ''}>Editor</option>
  <option value="admin" ${adminData.role === 'admin' ? 'selected' : ''}>Admin</option>
  <option value="Super Admin" ${adminData.role === 'super admin' ? 'selected' : ''}>Super Admin</option>
</select>`
```